# Local usage of maven dependency with provided scope

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I need to use external framework in my code.
I've added dependency to my pom.xml. But the problem is that we need to use the same jar across all out project on the remote host, thus we use `<scope>provided</scope>`
And every thing works good if i run my project on the remote host, but when i run it locally i get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```

I've checked - my local repository contains dependency, but still i can't use it.
Where should i put my *jar file to make it accessible for my application ?

**UPDATE:**
We use Jetty, but very often we run java code from ruby scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your local environment the same as the one your targeting for production since dependencies with scope 'provided' will not be provided by maven at runtime.

You don't say what your using to run your code but assuming you tomcat you could put the .jar file in the shared library directory at $CATALINA_HOME/lib